# I want to insert value using switch value.

Tags: php

I try solve the problem more but failed.  I want to input a number and then I want to change it via '**switch**' like 80= A+ . But I could not . Please help me and take a great thanks.

```
<form method="post" action=" " >

            <table width="400" align="center">

                <tr><td>     Marks <td><input type="text" name="marks"></td></tr>

                <tr><td>      Click on the Button <td><input  type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
            </table>

        </form>



      <?php 

      $servername = "localhost"; 
      $username = "root"; 
      $password = ""; 
      $dbname = "zidm"; 
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $marks=$_POST['marks'];


     $marks = switch ($marks) {
        case ($marks>"50"):
            echo "B";
            break;

        default:
            echo "C";
            break;
     }

    $sql="INSERT INTO profile (id, name) VALUES ('', '$marks')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     ?>
```

Comment: Why echo?  You don't want to output it, you want to save it to the database, so create a new variable and store the letter in it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do this after `$marks = $_POST['marks'];`

```
switch (true) {
    case ($marks > "50"):
        $marks = "B";
        break;
    default:
        $marks = "C";
        break;
 }
```

I edited the condition inside the switch block, as my original answer contained a wrong one. You can store multiple conditions in a `switch`, substituing an `if-else-else-else...` chain with a `switch (true)` and conditions you want to check in each `case`.

Answer (score 4):

That's not how switch works.

Switch doesn't return anything. It's just like an if-else, it executes the code block according to a matching value.

Also you can't have a conditional operation on the clauses (unless the switched expression is a boolean).

I think you should simply use if-elses instead, or simply use a ternary:

```
$marks = $_POST['marks'];

$marks = ($marks > 50) ? 'B' : 'C';
```